# How to implement a ScheduledExecutorService on top of a ExecutorService instance?

Tags: java

We have one central ExecutorService instance, that we try to use everywhere in our application server.

Unfortunately, we should now also use some library that wants a ScheduledExecutorService.

How do I get a ScheduledExecutorService, that is a wrapper on top of our ExecutorService instance?

It looks like Guava and Apache commons-* do not have that (or I was not able to recognize it).

EDIT: I've researched why we have a custom ExecutorService. Some "tasks" (Runnables) should be run as *daemon*, and others not. But *you cannot change the "daemon" flag after thread creation*. So *we have 2 ExecutorService instances*, which extend ThreadPoolExecutor. Also, we do some stuff before and after running the Runnables (like setting up the "logging configuration"). Finally, we have a custom ExecutorService "wrapper", which act as our central ExecutorService instance, and based on "task instanceof DaemonRunnable", delegates to either of the real ExecutorServices.

So, if there isn't a better option, we could extend ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instead of ThreadPoolExecutor, and implement delegation for the missing methods from ScheduledExecutorService into the "wrapper".

Basically, my question was if we need to do this, or if some ScheduledExecutorService implementation wrapping an ExecutorService already exists in a "standard" library, that we could just use.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your issue is. Could you elaborate a little bit more? `ScheduledExecutorService` extends `ExecutorService` so it has all the functionality of the `ExecutorService` as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, ScheduledExecutorService extends ExecutorService, but *our* ExecutorService does not implement ScheduledExecutorService, and we are looking for a way to NOT have to implement, and test, the missing functionality ourselves, as this would be tricks, and time consuming, and our impl would probably contain bugs.

Comment: Just initialize it as `ScheduledExecutorService`. You will be able to use it as `ExecutorService` in all the places that you used to, no changes needed there.

Comment: Or are you saying that you've implemented your own `ExecutorService` from the ground up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is available as part of Java language. If you want to make a separate wrapper over ExecutorService that would provide ScheduledExecutorService functionality you will have to write it yourself, but that would be a waste of time. What you need to do is to have your central ExecutorService instance to be an instance of ScheduledExecutorService. Note that ScheduledExecutorService extends ExecutorService and thus could be used as ExecutorService or ScheduledExecutorService as needed.